# Добавить title в description React Helmet

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Всем привет! В проекте, в файле шаблона используется React Helmet. Нужно добавить title в description, чтобы получилось как то так: `<meta name="description" content={title}{meta.description}/>`

Но так он выдает естественно ошибку. Если взять их оба в кавычки, то он просто пишет в кавычках "{title}{meta.description}", не вызывая их. Как передать в content оба значения?

```js
{meta &&
    <Helmet>
        {meta.title ? <title>{meta.title}</title> : <title>{title}</title>}
        {meta.description ? <meta name="description" content={meta.description}/> : <meta name="description" content={meta.description}{title}/>}
        <meta property="og:url" content={typeof window === 'undefined' ? null : window.location.href}/>
    </Helmet>
}
```